# Getting a list of date ranges that occur between the ranges of two lists of date ranges

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, date-comparison

Given I have a list of `KeyValuePair<DateTime,DateTime>` (which represent date ranges available), and I have another list of same type (which represent date ranges not available), then I need to end up with a list of date ranges that are within the first list's ranges, but with ranges in first list being sliced by ranges in the second list. It may be that second list only has one entry, but it covers the entire available range, in which case the result should be empty.

To illustrate:

```
available: |~|   |~~~~|   |~~|      |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
unavailab:   |~~~~~~~~~| |~|   |~~~~~~|       |~~~~~~~~|
expected : |~|             |~|        |~~~~~~~|        |~~|
```

Or, in code, if you prefer (not same as illustration):

```
IList<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> scheduleDates = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 12, 0, 0)),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 15, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 21, 0, 0))
        };

IList<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> holidayDates = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 16, 0, 0)),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 17, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 18, 0, 0)),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 24, 0, 0)),
        };

IList<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>> availability = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 11, 0, 0)),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 17, 0, 0)),
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2016, 11, 15, 20, 0, 0))
        };
```

What would be the most efficient method of doing this? I can only think of a brute force, and surely that's not the way to go. Note that both input lists and/or the output list could be empty.

Comment: I don't know of any magical method to achieve this. You should try writing something and post your code.

Comment: sorting lists based on date Diff can be a good point to start

Comment: Can you explain the link between available/unavailab/expected in your diagram and the collections in the code?

Comment: I have a nuget package that can help you - Intervals.LVK - you can find a .NET Fiddle showing how [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRa5E0).

Comment: Lasse, I love you. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as the solution :)

Comment: Since the answer goes in the form of a "use this nuget package that I wrote", I'd rather not. To post a good answer here is a rather big undertaking for this particular question. Also, far from it that my nuget package has the best implementation of such an algorithm, I'm pretty sure someone will come up with a LINQ query in 4 lines of code that does the job.

Comment: I've done something very similar to this before. It ended up having to be custom logic, using something very similar to the Zip method available in LINQ. 

Basics are:
1. get an enumerator for each list
2. execute logic for which value should be used
3. advance list(s) as necessary
4. if one of the lists is empty, merge in all results from the remaining list

I did this for benchmarks that had daily valuations going back to the 1960's and it ran in < 16 ms for the entire range of dates.

Comment: I guess the thing was that I have trouble figuring out where to even begin with this kind of stuff in a remotely algorithmic way, so even a ish-implementation that produces accurate results, works for these purposes :) Obviously if there's a more performant solution, I'll take it!